# Does continuity of $f(x)$ imply continuity of $f^{(n)}(x)$? And other questions.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

I'm working on a proof of the product rule for derivatives using Taylor Series, and the following questions have come up in the process. I'm suspecting that the answer to each of these questions is yes, but I have not idea how to prove such a thing.

Setup:

Let $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ be some interval. Let $f:\Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb R$ be continuous on $I$.

Question 1:

Does the continuity of $f(x)$ on $I$ imply the continuity of $f^{(n)}(x)$ on $I$, where $n\in N=\Bbb N\cup \{0\}$?

Question 2:

If $g:\Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb R$ is also continuous on $I$, is $u(x)=f(x)g(x)$ also continuous on $I$?

Could you give proofs?

Edit: I've gotten the second one figured out from the limit of a product is the product of the limits. Still need help with the proof of the first one.

Edit 2.0: The first one is FALSE! (dun dun dun) See the comment thread for a good counterexample by Randall.

Comment: Both are YES...

Comment: @Topo why? Which theorems give this? I need proof.

Comment: Are you assuming all those derivatives fully exist?  Otherwise $|x|$.

Comment: @clathratus What you have tried so far for the proof?

Comment: @Topo I don't know how to start

Comment: @Randall what do you mean?

Comment: @Topo I was thinking that the product of two continuous functions would be continuous because that sort of thing makes sense... :( Sadly "making sense" isn't a theorem.

Comment: $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous over the whole real line, but not differentiable at $x=0$.  Same problem for things like $\sqrt[3]{x}$....

Comment: @Randall I'm assuming that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable for all $x\in I$

Comment: @clathratus  your second question follows immediately from a limit law:  the limit of a product is the product of the limits (if both of the latter exist, which you assume they do).

Comment: @Randall Thank you. Updated the question.

Comment: Also, I think the first is false by something like $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.  The derivative satisfies the intermediate value property but $f'$ is not continuous (even though $f$ is continuous and differentiable).  I could be rusty, though.

Comment: Assuming $f^n(x)$ means $(f\cdot f \cdot ... \cdot f)(x)$ you can use the same argument you used in order to proof the 2nd question.

Comment: Zest raises a good point.  What do you mean by $f^{(n)}$?  Powers or derivatives?  I've assumed the latter.

Comment: @Zest,Randall $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)$ w.r.t $x$

Comment: @Topo if you were asking about the proof of the power rule with Taylor series, I've finished it, but I'm just trying to make sure it's not obviously erroneous before I post it on here for further inspection.

Comment: Since $f^n(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative, @Randall's example is a good counterexample. $f$ is differentiable, but its derivative $f'$ is not continous at $x=0$.

Comment: @Zest Okay thank you. I'll update the question.

Comment: Someone (not me) should write up all the details in an answer....

Comment: @Randall I choose Zest to do it

Comment: i'll gladly do so.

Comment: Since you mention Taylor series: If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-c)^n$ and this converges for every value of $x\in\mathbb C$ within a distance $R$ of $c,$ then $f$ has derivatives of all orders, i.e. $f^{(n)}(x)$ exists for all $n\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and every $x\in\mathbb C$ within the distance $R$ of $c.$ (And "within" in this case means the distance is strictly less than $R$.) Functions defined by convergent power series are rather well behaved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to answer the first Question i'll elaborate Randalls (see comments) chosen function

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
  x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}),  & x\not= 0 \\
  0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is differentiable at every point. For its derivative $f'$ we get

$$ f'(x)=\begin{cases}
  2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x}),  & x\not= 0 \\
  0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$

which is not continous at $x = 0$.

Proof:

In order to prove $f'$ is not continous for $x=0$, we show the following

$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \forall\delta > 0\ \exists x \in \mathbb{R} : \vert x-0\vert < \delta \wedge \vert f'(x)-f'(0)\vert > \varepsilon$$

If we choose $x = \frac{1}{n\pi}$ we have

$$ \vert \frac{1}{n\pi}\vert < \delta \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\delta\pi} < n $$

which leads us to

$$ \vert f'(x) - f'(0) \vert = \left\vert f'\left(\frac{1}{n\pi}\right)\right\vert = \left\vert 2\frac{1}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi)-\cos(n\pi) \right\vert = \vert 0 \pm 1 \vert = 1 >   \frac{1}{2}=:\varepsilon$$

Therefore $f'$ is not continous at $x=0$

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: We can also construct a strictly increasing differentiable $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $\{f'(x): x\in [0,1]\}$ is unbounded above, and such that $f'(x)$ is continuous except at  $x=1.$

Comment: Znest. Very nice!